# Software to document code?

Tags: php, testing, pseudocode

I need to document and create a list of variables in my code as part of my A Level computing coursework, however my PHP script is over 6,000 lines in total.

Does anyone know of any software that will display a list of variables within my code? I really don't feel like going through all of my code and hand-picking out about a thousand variables :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) allows you to parse the script and could be used to pick out all the variables defined/used

Comment: Thanks dude! After about an hour of reading around, I finally worked it out! It was as simple as calling a function  $tokens = token_get_all("filename.php"); then looping over the result and checking if it's equal to a T_VARIABLE :)

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell this would be quite trivial:

```
Select-String '\$[\w_]+' foo.php -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches |
  Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty Value
```

or shorter:

```
sls -a '\$[\w_]+' foo.php|%{$_.Matches}|select -u -exp Value
```

Adapt accordingly for Perl, sed, or whatever you like to use. The basic idea would be the same.

Comment: Cool idea!  Of course, this is only catching stuff beginning with `$`, right?  I wonder if he also needs constants declared with `define()` and what not.

Comment: Well, constants are not variables, at least in my understanding ;-) (although I wonder why someone needs a list of all variables in a program anyway).

Comment: Agreed, it seems ridiculous that someone would want such a list.  :-D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like you put quite some effort into it, so I'm going to +1 you. However, being the n00b that I am, I couldn't figure out how to use PowerShell. I've only just figured out how to use PHP within a localhost server, and that's after like a year of learning!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how detailed you need to be, [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) might be useful here.

You should also look into the Reflection classes:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php  Writing something up using Reflection would give you control over the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep -oh "\$[a-zA-Z_]*" file.php | sort | uniq
```

or

```
$ grep -R -oh "\$[a-zA-Z_]*" src_dir | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Same as I said to @Joey - Great answer, but I don't know how to run this code :( +1 for your time and effort though :)